# How to retrieve production environment endpoint

Tags: docusignapi

I've certified my integrator key last week and it was confirmed to go "live" last friday.
Reading [this documentation](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/API%20Certification%20Guide.pdf), I now need to determine which production site I am linked to. The problem is that when I follow the instructions, I can't see which site I am linked to :

```
*The {SERVER} value is determined by where your DocuSign Production account resides.
The easiest way to determine this is to login to your Production DocuSign account and
examine the prefix of the URL. For example, if the URL is:
https://na2.docusign.net/Member/Home.aspx, then replace {SERVER} with “na2” to find
your Production endpoints.
```

Any help would be appreciated

is there a way to retrieve the Production URL from an envelope ?

```
envelopeApi.GetEnvelope() ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Login_Information](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/) API to retrieve your BaseUrl.

Here is the code using the [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/core_recipes/CoreRecipes.cs#L605-L643)

```cs
string _username = "<Add your User Name>";
string _password = "<Add your Password>";
string _integratorKey = "<Add your Integrator Key>";
string DOCUSIGN_URI = "https://www.docusign.net/restapi";
string _authHeader;

public string Init()
{
     _authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
    // initialize client for desired environment (for production change to www)
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(DOCUSIGN_URI);
    Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

    Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", _authHeader);

    // we will retrieve this from the login API call
    string accountId = null;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1: LOGIN API        
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // login call is available in the authentication api 
    AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
    LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

    // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
    accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;

    string baseUrl = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl;
    // Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
    apiClient = new ApiClient(baseUrl);

    return accountId;
}
```