# Docusign C# CreateEnvelope error - Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl, docusignapi, tls1.2

After the go live process, I created the new keys and I am using them as well. But I got this error

`Error calling CreateEnvelope: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.`

I am using a c# application. The exception is thrown in the Create Envelope method:

```
EnvelopeDefinition Envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
       EmailSubject = EmailSubject,
       Documents = EnvelopeDocuments,
       Recipients = new Recipients { Signers = Signers },
       Status = "sent"
};

return GetEnvelopesApi().CreateEnvelope(_AccountId, Envelope).EnvelopeId;
```

Where GetEnvelopesApi just call the `public EnvelopesApi(Configuration configuration = null);` of docusign.esign.api :

```
 private EnvelopesApi GetEnvelopesApi()
 {
      ApiClient Client = new ApiClient("https://docusign.net/restapi");

      Client.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());

      return new EnvelopesApi(Client.Configuration);
 }
```

If I use my developer demo keys instead of the production ones,  and "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi" instead of the production url, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did to get to the error message

```
{"errorCode":"USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP",
 "message": "The UserID does not have a valid membership in this Account."}
```

was **correct**.

Next, you need to solve the problem that causes the USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP error. It is probably due to you continuing to use a UserId (guid format) from the developer (demo) account. You need to use a UserId from your production account.

Also note that you must determine what the **base url** is for your account. That determines if you should use **[www.docusign.net](http://www.docusign.net)** in production, or ***na2.docusign.net*** or something else.

You can determine the base url for your account manually or automatically. But it must be correct... Ask another question if you need help on that subject.

Comment: I think I am using the correct UserId. 

At https://admin.docusign.com/api-integrator-key , under My Account Information --> 
API Username. 

That API UserName is the same as the admin User (DS Admin) , that it is supposed to have permission for all the actions.

Comment: I found, by using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984709/how-to-retrieve-production-environment-endpoint , that my baseUrl is https://au.docusign.net/restapi/ but didn't work either using it

Comment: As I said, by using the link above I got my baseUrl , something like : 

https://au.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/123456789

That's the one it worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the lack of `https`, so you need to change the url to `https://docusign.net/restapi`

**UPDATE**

I think I found your issue! The url should be `https://www.docusign.net/restapi` due to the fact the ssl certificate is signed to use `www.` and gives you a certificate error when you don't have it

**UPDATE 2**

Add the following line before to make the connection:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

That is in order to force the connection to use TLS 1.2

Also, I would suggest you to debug it inside the function so you know where it breaks within it

**UPDATE 3**

In case you still receive the SSL/TLS issue, you could try to add the following line before your rest call too:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: sorry, that was me testing. It is https, I have changed it back now

Comment: I have tried adding the www. and still doesn't work

Comment: Update 2 didn't work for me.

Update 3 gave me this error message: 

Error calling CreateEnvelope: 

{"errorCode":"USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP","message":
"The UserID does not have a valid membership in this Account."}

Comment: Ok, so there's a problem with the trust between the certificate, that's what the Update 3 bypasses, then the next issue is clear: `UserID does not have a valid membership in this Account` so you are one step closer. The issue here is the production keys might not work or doesn't have the appropriate privileges. I would suggest you to use Postman and try to do the same REST call and see the response (using the same token)